# How can I block or deactivate Excel 4.0 macros?

Tags: excel, macros, settings, xlm, excel-4.0

The only correct hint I found was in a screenshot of Excel settings (but these were in German). Is it at all possible to deactivate macros or macro sheets in Excel 4.0 or to always prevent them from being executed?

[image]

<sup>https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/deutsch/excel-options-trust-center-new-excel-4-0-macro-setting/idi-p/2222066</sup>

However, the option shown in the screenshot is not to be found in my Excel settings.

Comment: Do the opposite of what is explained here [Working with Excel 4.0 macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-excel-4-0-macros-ba8924d4-e157-4bb2-8d76-2c07ff02e0b8) and they will not execute. If you found that checkbox already why don't you untick it? The point of your question is not really clear as the solution is already in your question. If not please be more precise and [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Trust Center settings, when a separate check box for Excel 4.0 macros does not exist, disabling all macros will also disable Excel 4.0 macros.

[image]